# How to reset static variable or how to create the get_length function for a binary tree?

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I've decided to store an array into a binary tree, so that all elements of array locate on right side of tree. How to count all of these elements?

```
int get_length(Node * array) {
   static int len = 0;
   if (array == NULL) return len;
   else {
       len++;
       get_length(array->right);
   }
}
```

Problem in static variable: after each usage of this function, variable `len` is not reset and the returned length is incorrect. After each usage that variable will be increased.

Comment: Don't use `static`. Use the return value from each recursive call. As it is, your code doesn't even return anything in some paths even though it is declared to do so.

Comment: You don't have a return statement..

Comment: Like how? Can you give me simple example, please? Guess I don't get it.

Comment: If you don't want to change the signature of the function, then you may have to create another variable and assign the static value to it. Just before the return, reset static variable and return newly created variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `static`. Accumulate the return value of the recursive call. For example:

```
int get_length(Node * array) {
   if (array == NULL) return 0;
   else {
       return 1+get_length(array->right);
   }
}
```

Comment: O, very nice. Thank you very much!

Comment: +1 Because that's the answer I was going to write (and that I don't need to add anymore). I would just have added an iterative solution (because recursion is not a doctor's order when it is not clear how to implement it)(and because the stack says 'thanks', especially within an embedded system).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to pass the len:

```
int get_length(Node * array, int len) {
   if (array == NULL) return len;
   else {
       return get_length(array->right, len + 1);
   }
}
```

Avoid using recursion when there is an iterative solution:

```
int get_length(Node * array) {
   int len = 0;

   while (array) {
       array = array->right;
       len++;
   }
   return len;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I though about it, but is a good solution to pass the length to function that return the length? :)

Comment: @Evgeniy why not?, otherwise (using a `static`) your function is not reusable: each time you call the function from the outside it accumulates the previous stored value, (it may not be what you want).

Comment: You are welcome, anyway, I prefer @kaylum answer (it doesn't need to pass the len)

Comment: Yeah, I like it too